# How to assemble network traffic linked to an android application?

Tags: android, capture, monitor, pcap, network-traffic

How to assemble network traffic linked to an android application?

For example:

```
time, source, destination, protocol, application_name 
13.0,83833 172.16.253.158, 172.18.253,158, Skype
```

Comment: That should not be possible, except on rooted devices, custom ROMs, or if you implement a `VpnService` and the user agrees to make your app be their VPN.

Comment: 1. I have rooted android device
2. I capture traffic in my device

Comment: You mean you want to associate the 5-tuple with the sending/receiving process? How are you currently capturing traffic on the device?